# My css animation slideshow gets stuck on the final image

Tags: html, css, css-animations, slideshow

Trying to figure out why the css crossfade animation is getting stuck on the final image, instead of just replaying from the beginning.

The slideshow gets stuck on the last image, and some other subsequent images appear intermittently.

Here's some of the pertinent css and html.

What am I missing? Did I get the timing wrong?

html:

```
  <div class="crossfade">
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
  </div>
```

css:

```
  .crossfade > figure {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:left top;
  color: transparent;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top:70px;
  z-index: 1000;
  left:0px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation linear infinite 0s;
  animation-duration:18s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; 

  }



  .crossfade > figure:nth-child(1) { 
    animation-delay: 0s;
    background-image: url(../images/slideshow/animation-1.jpg);
  }


  .crossfade > figure:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
    background-image:url(../images/slideshow/animation-2.jpg);
  }


  .crossfade > figure:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
    background-image: url(../images/slideshow/animation-3.jpg);
  }


  .crossfade > figure:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 9s;    
    background-image: url(../images/slideshow/animation-4.jpg);
  }


  .crossfade > figure:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 12s;   
    background-image: url(../images/slideshow/animation-5.jpg);
  }


  .crossfade > figure:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 15s;   
    background-image: url(../images/slideshow/animation-6.jpg);
  }




  @keyframes 
  imageAnimation {  0% {
   animation-timing-function: ease-in;
   opacity: 0;
  }
   10% {
   animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   opacity: 1;
  }
   17% {
   opacity: 1
  }
   90% {
   opacity: 1
  }
   100% {
   opacity: 0
  }
  }
```